Not able to install Graph Connector Agent in my computer
Microsoft Graph Connector Agent
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=104045
It auto rolls back , everytime. I need this installed successfully to make Graph Connector work.
enter image description here
My system check :
enter image description here
Any help would be appreciated. Feel free to add other expert for better visibility.

Somit,
Did you check your Execution Policy?  I had the same issue and once I Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned, it worked.

Yes, it was set to
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

I ran into this same issue and was able to get the install to work by uninstalling .NET Core Desktop Runtime 8.0 and installing .NET SDK 8.0.306.
Not sure why this worked as Microsoft's documentation specifically says to install .NET Core Desktop Runtime 8.0.
